# Car Detection positive samples of different sizes and aspect ratios

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, cascade-classifier

I have read that positive sample for car detection should be of the same size or at least same aspect ratio. However, I   have a car dataset that after cropping images have different sizes or aspect ratios. So what shall i do?

I am using the Stanford car Dataset http://ai.stanford.edu/~jkrause/cars/car_dataset.html
After Cropping Cars I found that all images have the same aspect ratio. Does this is enough for training? Or i have to resize all images to the same size?

Comment: Show us what you already tried, and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: add a border before cropping to get the desired aspect ratio

Comment: @micka  What do u mean by adding a border?

Comment: if you want an aspect ratio of 2:1 and your object is sized 34x13 pixel you should add 2 pixels on top and 2 pixels on the bottom from the background to your object region before cropping. After that your cropped image will be 34x17 which is 2:1

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671278/computer-vision-is-it-necessary-to-have-multi-classifiers-with-certain-viewpoi

If the vehicles in your data aren't the same relative size, you will need to search across multiple scales (i.e. resize images up/down)

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. When i get back to the car dataset, i found differences in the aspect ratio. What i should i do now?. In addition, I found that cars  are not of the same size. So do you recommend to adjust the aspect ratio to have a unified ratio across the dataset and then i should start to resolve the problem of different car sizes? If so, how it can be done?